# Flutter, when i send notification from firebase messaging i get this error and my app freeze

Tags: firebase, flutter, messaging

[image: f]

DequeueBuffer: dequeueBuffer failed

flush reason set to EsxFlushModeReasonInvalidBinLayout

Any help please guys?

Comment: There' an open issue for the same on GitHub https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35900

Comment: Did you implement it well

Comment: Did you add FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK in your androidmanifest

Comment: Yes i did FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK and i implement it well, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys
I fixed it now, you should downgrade flutter